# Can we fill a balloon with gas and make it electric charged so it lighter than air?

Tags: electricity, charge, buoyancy

Suppose we have a membrane that not chemically react to make a balloon and we seal airtight then steal electron from gas atom inside to make it positively charged and repel each other. Is it possible to make it float?

Comment: Consider it will have higher internal energy due to that configuration. This will result is some positive Delta *m*.

Comment: to float  there should be buoyancy (hydrogen or helium balloons) which has nothing to do with charge. You will just have a charged balloon and depending on the surroundings it may spark and become neutral,

Comment: @annav What I said about charged is, when atom being positively or negatively charged, it would repel each other so it would act like hot air, has more pressure than neutral with the same mass, so it should be less dense than normal air. So if we sealed those charged atom inside insulator it should make it expand like a balloon